# why react-script build fails in cmd but succuss in npm scripts(npm run build)?

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, react-scripts

[image]

command react-scripts build always fails even though react-scripts.cmd exists under folder node_modules/.bin/
strangely: npm run build(build: react-scripts build) will run successfully

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages. They can not be indexed by Google and so it doesn't help other people.

Answer (score 2):

You probably not installed `react-script` globally, therefore it is located in the local node_module.

You can run it with `npx`

```
npx react-script build
```

or provide a path to it...

Comment: Thanks. Installing globally has solved my problem. npx is also useful.The third solution might be: npm bin & react-scripts build.it will run locally

Answer (score 0):

1. Installing globally has solved my problem.
2. npx is also useful.
3. The third solution might be:

> ```
> npm bin 
> react-scripts build.
> ```

it will run locally